# Extract delimiter-splitted elements while also retaining the looping variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am a beginner in bash, and I am trying to loop through a list of phrases, and my objective is to

A) split each phrase using `.` and then extract the first split element

B) also have the original phrase available

My pseudocode/attempt looks like this -

```bsh
    while read x
    do
        eval "whole_phrase=$x" # store the whole phrase to another variable
        eval "first_element=echo $x | cut -d';' -f1" # extract the first element after splitting
        myprogram -i ../$first_element -o ../$whole_phrase
    done < ListOfDotSeparatedPhrases.txt
```

This is how `ListOfDotSeparatedPhrases.txt` looks like -

```
18T3L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
35T10R.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
18T6L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
40T4LAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
22T10L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
38T7L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
```

I have been trying to search online for the best way to do this, but have failed. Any ideas? I am sure this is actually not very difficult!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

`eval "whole_phrase=$x" # store the whole phrase to another variable`

Better is:

`whole_phrase="$x"`

And given:

`eval "first_element=echo $x | cut -d';' -f1" # extract the first element after splitting`

there are many ways to extract the first element.

Since your delimiter is the period character or `.`, pass that to `awk` and ask it to print just the first field:

`first_element="$(awk -F. '{print $1}' <<< "$x")"`

Or, since in this special case you want only the first element, it's easy to tell `sed` to delete the first `.` character and everything after it:

`first_element="$(sed -e 's/\..*//' <<< "$x")"`

Finally, consider that so long as you don't alter the variable `x` that you read from your file, you already have the `whole_phrase` value there.  Indeed, you could use that variable name in your `while` loop:

```
while read whole_phrase
do
    first_element="$(awk -F. '{print $1}' <<< "$whole_phrase")"
    myprogram -i "../$first_element" -o "../$whole_phrase"
done < ListOfDotSeparatedPhrases.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I like this slightly better than the other answer since I find it more satisfying having the two entities as separate defined variables that I can work with later!

Answer (score 2):

How about letting `read` do the splitting for you, setting the field separator to `.`?

```
while IFS=. read -r first_element remainder; do 
  echo myprogram -i "../$first_element" -o "../${first_element}.${remainder}"
done < ListOfDotSeparatedPhrases.txt 
myprogram -i ../18T3L -o ../18T3L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
myprogram -i ../35T10R -o ../35T10R.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
myprogram -i ../18T6L -o ../18T6L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
myprogram -i ../40T4LAligned -o ../40T4LAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
myprogram -i ../22T10L -o ../22T10L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
myprogram -i ../38T7L -o ../38T7L.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
```

From `man bash`:

```
read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p
       prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
              One line is read from the  standard  input,  or  from  the  file
              descriptor  fd  supplied  as an argument to the -u option, split
              into words as described above  under  Word  Splitting,  and  the
              first word is assigned to the first name, the second word to the
              second name, and so on.  If there are more words than names, the
              remaining words and their intervening delimiters are assigned to
              the last name.  If there are fewer words  read  from  the  input
              stream  than  names, the remaining names are assigned empty val‐
              ues.  The characters in IFS are used  to  split  the  line  into
              words  using  the  same  rules  the  shell  uses  for  expansion
              (described above under Word Splitting).
```

---

Alternatively (actually this is simpler - and more portable) read and retain the whole line, then use shell parameter expansion to generate the first element by removing the remainder:

```
while read -r x; do 
  myprogram -i "../${x%%.*}" -o "../$x"
done < ListOfDotSeparatedPhrases.txt
```

Comment: @Freddy oops good catch - thanks

Comment: this is amazing. Thanks a ton!